# Which LaunchImage values are not necessary in Images.xcassets in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios6

I have filled every field here. The problem is the size of the final ipa file.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to find a way to minimize this.

- I target iOS6+ and it is a universal app for both iPad and iPhone.
- StatusBar is hidden initially.
- My app supports all orientations.

I couldn't find the best way to do it. Are there any unnecessary files here?

**update**
After recommendation of @ParvendraSingh, compressed versions are far more usable. I will keep the question open to see if there are non-necessary values in xcassets file, as that will be a direct reply to my question.

[image]

**update2**
After checking the compressed versions, they are not usable enough as it is very easy to see the compression artifacts.

Comment: Just Compress your All Image with https://tinypng.com/......  and add again

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I checked the visuals, but they are unusable.. so much compression artifacts :/